# Swift filter only assessing one parameter?

Tags: swift

I am using a `filter` on a completion to sort my data.

`completion(calls.filter{$0?.email == "test@email.com" || $0?.callMade != true}.compactMap{ $0 })`

This seems to only check one parameter and if its true gives the data, I need both parameters to be assessed and qualified.

Am I using `||` incorrectly?

Comment: use && (and).. || is for OR

Comment: @DenisKozhukhov oh my. Thanks! Silly mistake.

Comment: If the first param is true it won't test the second as it only needs one to be true to satisfy the OR.

Comment: @flanker thanks for the explanation! Not sure how I got that confused

Comment: Think it through by speaking it out in your head: "Filter my array of calls to select only those calls who's email is "test@email.com" AND their callMade flag is true." That tells you which operator to use.

Comment: Point of order: You said "I am using a filter on a completion to sort my data". Your code is *filtering* your array of results, not *sorting* it.

Comment: Why do you have an array of Optional Calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with the and vs. or problem, which has been addressed in comments already, you should do unwrapping earlier, to avoid the noise of question marks.

And don't use `!= true`. It's the most complex way to express what can alternatively be expressed as `== false`, or `!`. (Unless that's also optional. In which case, you again probably have too many optionals, and you should post your code.)

```swift
calls
  .compactMap { $0 }
  .filter { $0.email == "test@email.com" && !$0.callMade }
```

Also, make sure there's even a reason for the calls to be optional in the first place.